# Converting SQL command from vb .net to C#

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to analyze SQL command text in vb.net and integrate it to be compatible with C#.

I am having issues converting SQL command text from vb.net to c#.

I used Telerik: http://converter.telerik.com/

and got these results (shown below). I was wondering if someone who is familiar with both VB.NET and C# could help me re-write the full SQL command text.

Original vb.net command text:

```
Dim r As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

Do While True
    If r.Read() Then
         SQL2 = "SELECT * from Invoices "
         SQL2 = SQL2 & " WHERE Num = '" & r("Num") & "'"

         conPubs2 = New SqlConnection(<ConnectionString>)
         sqlCommand2 = New SqlCommand(SQL2, conPubs2)
         conPubs2.Open()

         Dim r2 As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()

         Do While True
             If r2.Read() Then
                 MsgBox(RTrim(r("Num")) & ": " & RTrim(r2("ItemID")))
             Else
                 Exit Do
             End If
         Loop

    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

conPubs.Close()
conPubs2.Close()

End Sub
```

Here's what I got in C# when I used Telerik's online converter:

```
SqlDataReader r = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (true)
{
    if (r.Read())
    {
        SQL2 = "SELECT * from Invoices ";
        SQL2 = SQL2 + " WHERE Num = '" + r("Num") + "'";
```

> /* Cannot convert AssignmentStatementSyntax, CONVERSION ERROR: Conversion for XmlElement not implemented, please report this issue in ')
>   sql...' at character 314
>
> at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.NodesVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.VisitXmlElement(XmlElementSyntax node)
>
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.XmlElementSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
>
>   at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingNodesVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
>
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.VisitXmlElement(XmlElementSyntax node)
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.XmlElementSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>
>   at  ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.NodesVisitor.VisitSimpleArgument(SimpleArgumentSyntax node)
>
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SimpleArgumentSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
>
>   at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingNodesVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.VisitSimpleArgument(SimpleArgumentSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SimpleArgumentSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.NodesVisitor.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<ConvertArguments>b__0(ArgumentSyntax a, Int32 i)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__5`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList[TNode](IEnumerable`1 nodes)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.NodesVisitor.VisitArgumentList(ArgumentListSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ArgumentListSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingNodesVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.VisitArgumentList(ArgumentListSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ArgumentListSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.NodesVisitor.VisitObjectCreationExpression(ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingNodesVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.VisitObjectCreationExpression(ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.VisualBasicConverter.MethodBodyVisitor.VisitAssignmentStatement(AssignmentStatementSyntax node)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.AssignmentStatementSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingMethodBodyVisitor.ConvertWithTrivia(SyntaxNode node)
>      at ICSharpCode.CodeConverter.CSharp.CommentConvertingMethodBodyVisitor.DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)

I am trying ultimately, to expand on a different query that has the following command text; the reason why is I need to expand upon it is to be able to count the total number of lines associated with the Num (lines returned, e.g. if more than 1):

```
dbConnection.Open();
var sqlCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT [ItemID], [Num]
                       FROM [Test].[dbo].[Invoices]
                       WHERE Num = '" + orderNumber.ToString() + "'";
```

Comment: `New SqlConnection(<ConnectionString>)` isn't even valid syntax for VB.NET, so fix that (passing "" should be sufficient for this purpose) and retry the conversion. However, this is *very bad* VB.NET  code to begin with, so you're going to get equally bad C# code out of a conversion. You'd be much better off figuring out the end goal of that code and rewriting the C# code from scratch.

Comment: Agreed.  It looks like `<ConnectionString>` is a placeholder which is replaced, in the code, as some sort of precompile step.

Comment: gosh! I need to think about what you are telling me. I will think on this and get back soon. thank you.

Comment: Please post the entire method. Then @ me to let me know it's all there. I'm confident I can convert this, but it would be malpractice to do it without fixing the crazy sql injection security issue at the same time, and that's better done if I can see the surrounding code. There's a good chance I can improve performance by an order of magnitude, also.

Comment: Please don't convert this code to anything! This is a long time to hold a connection open. For heavens sake, the code even shows a message box while the connection is open. What if the user goes to lunch. Just start over.

Comment: What is the datatype in the database of the Invoices.Num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK as for the first part concerning **conversion**, first of all, you did not copy the whole code of VB.Net, it was missing many parts **IN ORDER TO be correctly converted** to C# code, I did some implementations and converted it in the same website you used.
**The VB.Net [As it should be]**, it doesn't mean that is written in a correct way or won't generate errors.

```
Sub Hello()
        Dim conPubs As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Your_ConnectionString"}
        conPubs.Open()
        Dim ThisCommand1 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand 'This line was missing from the example you copied this from.
        Dim r As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = ThisCommand1.ExecuteReader
        Do While True
            If r.Read() Then
                Dim SQL2 As String = "SELECT * from Invoices WHERE Num = '" & r("Num") & "'"
                Dim conPubs2 = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("")
                Dim sqlCommand2 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL2, conPubs2)
                conPubs2.Open()
                Dim r2 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()
                Do While True
                    If r2.Read() Then
                        MsgBox(RTrim(r("Num")) & ": " & RTrim(r2("ItemID")))
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
                conPubs2.Close()       'Is a second SqlServer Connection
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        conPubs.Close()      'Is SqlServer Connection
    End Sub
```

The Conversion to C# :

```
public void Hello()
{
    SqlClient.SqlConnection conPubs = new SqlClient.SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = "Your_ConnectionString" };
    conPubs.Open();
    SqlClient.SqlCommand ThisCommand1 = new SqlClient.SqlCommand(); // This line was missing from the example you copied this from.
    SqlClient.SqlDataReader r = ThisCommand1.ExecuteReader;
    while (true)
    {
        if (r.Read())
        {
            string SQL2 = "SELECT * from Invoices WHERE Num = '" + r("Num") + "'";
            var conPubs2 = new SqlClient.SqlConnection("");
            var sqlCommand2 = new SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL2, conPubs2);
            conPubs2.Open();
            SqlClient.SqlDataReader r2 = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            while (true)
            {
                if (r2.Read())
                    MsgBox(RTrim(r("Num")) + ": " + RTrim(r2("ItemID")));
                else
                    break;
            }
            conPubs2.Close();       // Is a second SqlServer Connection
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    conPubs.Close();      // Is SqlServer Connection
}
```

**Again, note :**

> This answers to your conversion issues, but doesn't mean that VB .Net
>   code is not going to generate Errors.

In VB.Net :

- VB.Net code needs to be re-written.
- Consider using [Using ... End Using] method with Database Connection.